Issue with Eigenfunction Expansion Method for Solving ODE in Mathematica
With the following Mathematica code, I am trying to solve a differential equation (ODE) using the eigenfunction expansion method. Unfortunately, when I compare the results obtained from this method with those from NDSolve, there are discrepancies. Through various experiments, I found that the eigenfunction expansion method produces a compressed version of the solution from NDSolve. Therefore, I assume that I might have forgotten a coefficient somewhere or included a redundant one. However, I can't find where.
Clear["Global`*"]

(* Initial conditions *)
init1 = y[0] == 0;
init2 = y[L] == 0;

(* Coefficient functions *)
a[x_] := 2;
b[x_] := x;
c[x_] := 3;
L = 2 Pi;

(* Define the ODE *)
ODE = Exp[Integrate[b[x]/a[x], x]] y''[x] + 
      Exp[Integrate[b[x]/a[x], x]] b[x]/a[x]*y'[x] + 
      Exp[Integrate[b[x]/a[x], x]] c[x]/a[x]*y[x] == 
      Exp[Integrate[b[x]/a[x], x]] f[x]/a[x];

(* Number of eigenfunctions to use *)
n0 = 3;

(* Compute eigenvalues and eigenfunctions *)
{eigV, eigF} = 
  NDEigensystem[{ODE[[1]], DirichletCondition[y[x] == 0, True]}, 
  y, {x, 0, L}, n0];

(* Right-hand side function *)
f[x_] := x^2;

(* Compute the coefficients for the eigenfunction expansion *)
yn[n_] := 
  NIntegrate[(f[x]*Exp[b[x]/a[x]]*eigF[[n]][x])/a[x], {x, 0, 
    L}]/(eigV[[n]]*NIntegrate[eigF[[n]][x]^2, {x, 0, L}]);

(* Approximate solution using the eigenfunction expansion *)
yAp[x_] := Sum[yn[j]*eigF[[j]][x], {j, 1, n0}];

(* Solve the ODE using NDSolve *)
sol = NDSolve[{ODE, init1, init2}, y[x], {x, 0, L}];
ySol[x_] := y[x] /. sol[[1]];

(* Plot the approximate solution *)
Plot[yAp[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "yAp"];

(* Plot the solution from NDSolve *)
Plot[ySol[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "ySol"];

(* Plot both solutions for comparison *)
Plot[{ySol[x], yAp[x]}, {x, 0, L}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"];


Are you sure you used correct normalization for the eigenfunctions when doing the sum? Also you only used 3 terms. What happens if you use more terms?

@Nasser , I bypassed the normalization of the eigenfunctions by thinking as follows:
Ly(x) = f(x) ⇔ L(Σyₙφₙ(x)) = f(x) ⇔ ΣyₙLφₙ(x) = f(x) ⇔ Σyₙλₙφₙ(x) = f(x).
Multiplying Σyₙλₙφₙ(x) = f(x) by φₙ(x), we have yₙ = (1/λₙ)<f,φₙ>/<φₙ,φₙ>.
In any case, even if φₙ were normalized, the yₙ would change, but ultimately yAp would be the same as now.

Try adding more terms to the sum and see of plot changes. I am assuming all your code is correct there.

@Nasser In the 4th term, it starts showing the error NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.944835}. NIntegrate obtained 1.5087666131437165 and 1.5777655818871566*^-6 for the integral and error estimates.. The same happens in the 6th and 22nd terms, etc. However, if I insist and plot the two solutions, I still have the same scaling problem.

@Nasser , I found my mistake. In the formula for calculating the yn coefficients, instead of multiplying f(x) by exp(∫b(x)/a(x)dx), I multiplied it by exp(b(x)/a(x)). I forgot the integral inside the exponential. This carelessness took up my whole morning...
Anyway, thank you for your interest!

The symbol $f(x)$ in line 4 is not defined.  The equal integral factors can be discarded. Later you define it as $x^2$, so $$y''(x)+\frac{1}{2} x y'(x)+\frac{3 y(x)}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}$$ is not a linear operator equation.
